# after installing arch linux cannot boot to other OS

Tags: arch-linux

I have installed Arch Linux, but I cannot boot to Ubuntu and Windows 8. they are not coming in the grub except Arch itself.

how to get back other OS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using UEFI you can select the boot manager directly from the firmware.

Additionally, you can install `os-prober` to search for other operating systems and update the Arch grub configuration.

Comment: how can I use os-prober, I don know